# AndroidLauncher libgdx Application errors?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I used to be able to run in android no problem, now the default launcher application has errors (`Bundle` and `super.onCreate`).

Also, it says the class needs to be abstract or to implement methods, I used to be able to run in android without even opening this file.
Need to be able to run in android now, any suggestions?

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {//error on this line, wants it to be abstract
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {//error here on bundle
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//error here on onCreate
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new Movement(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a library or the Android API is unloaded. Are you using Eclipse or IDEAS?

Comment: using android studio

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these error because you have not declared your OnCreate method with Override annotation. It is not your own method. so Your code should be like

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new Movement(), config);
}
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: nah it was an sdk issue